# How to use IN properly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a very complex query requirements, and now I simply use two tables as a demo:

```
mysql> select * from user_table;
+--------+------+------+
| name   | dep  | uid  |
+--------+------+------+
| frank  | IT   | 1001 |
| jack   | IT   | 1002 |
| Sissel | FA   | 1003 |
| Li     | IT   | 1004 |
| Mok    | PM   | 1005 |
+--------+------+------+
```

Second one:

```
mysql> select * from money_log;
+------+-------+
| uid  | money |
+------+-------+
| 1001 |  9989 |
| 1001 |    89 |
| 1001 |   189 |
| 1002 |   389 |
+------+-------+
```

And then I try to sum money by :

```
SELECT uid, sum(money) as moneys
FROM money_log
WHERE uid in (
    SELECT uid 
    FROM user_table
    WHERE dep='IT'
) 
GROUP BY uid;
```

The result is given those.

```
+------+--------+
| uid  | moneys |
+------+--------+
| 1001 |  10267 |
| 1002 |    389 |
+------+--------+
```

What I expect is :

```
+------+--------+
| uid  | moneys |
+------+--------+
| 1001 |  10267 |
| 1002 |    389 |
| 1004 |    0   |
+------+--------+
```

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `LEFT JOIN` instead

```
select u.uid, coalesce(sum(m.money),0) as money
from user_table u
left join money_log m on u.uid = m.uid  
where u.dep = 'IT'
group by u.uid
```

nb: Make sure you include the table alias to every column reference.

Comment: use coalesce() for that

Comment: @Used_byAlready is work, but is there any hack way to do this? I mean use `IN` can do this ?

Comment: Why? You can select the department without needing IN(). it's simply unnecessary